# Web Host selection

Tags: web-apps, java, hosted, asp.net

I would like to select a web host for my apps .
He is to support  ASP  and JSP Languages and at least MySQL DB
Please advise.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've had pretty good experiences with [HostHatch](https://hosthatch.com/a?id=193) (note, referral link).

By using a VPS you have full control over what is installed on the system, but the 'downfall' is that you have to set it up the way you want it.

This is ideal if you've had experience setting up your own server - but could be an issue if you have trouble with that sort of thing.

But one of the reasons I went with this group is their cheapest tier - it's given me plenty of time to fiddle without much investment.

They have some other options available too, but I haven't looked into them deeply.